# R crashing when running a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, stat

I am a r-beginner and have a code in which I am trying to do the average silhouette method. When I try to run a for loop, R stops with the error: R for Windows GUI front-end has stopped working. The code that I use is:

```
data_no_demographics<-read.csv(file.choose(),row.names=1)
data_no_demographics <- na.omit(data_no_demographics)
library(cluster)
k_max<-20
sil<-rep(0,k_max)
for(i in 2:k_max){
  km.res <- kmeans(scale(data_no_demographics), centers = i, nstart = 50)
  ss <- silhouette(km.res$cluster, scale(data_no_demographics))
  sil[i] <- mean(ss[, 3])
}
plot(1:k_max, sil, type = "b", pch = 20,col="black",frame = FALSE, xlab ="Number of clusters (k)", ylab="Average silhouette width (fit of data within its cluster)", main="Optimal number of clusters")
abline(v = which.max(sil), lty = 2, col="red")
```

Any help will be appreciated.

```
dput(data_no_demographics[1:4,])
```

Output: (data_structure(list(DRY.FOOD.MEAL.PREPARATION = c(0, 0, 0, 0),BASMATI.RICE =c(0.106274747, 0.086781763, 0.066892377, 0.039564525), JASMINE.RICE = c(0.037947215, 0.101672855, 0.025094901, 0.026354222), ITALIAN.RICE = c(0, 0.006335413, 0, 0), ORG.SIDE.DISHES = c(0, 0, 0, 0), COUSCOUS = c(0.014091056,  0.013493856, 0.009541397, 0.006704727), QUINOA = c(0.013921964, 0.020977683, 0.011593311, 0.006638343), FLAVOURED.RICE = c(0.322163823, 0.225682349, 0.378639581, 0.340580191), INSTANT.RICE = c(0.063184297, 0.044711557, 0.092459218, 0.152615507), PARBOILED.RICE = c(0.065396593, 0.089652796, 0.048548271, 0.032295539), RTH.SPECIALTY = c(0.010371018, 0.011771236, 0.009418283, 0.007833245), RTH.RICE = c(0.307790945, 
0.286375991, 0.29621422, 0.336331652), OTHER.RICE = c(0.013020136, 0.019484745, 0.010382682, 0.006737918), REGULAR.DRY.RICE = c(0.045838206, 0.093059756, 0.051215759, 0.044344132), READY.TO.EAT = c(0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("DRY.FOOD.MEAL.PREPARATION", "BASMATI.RICE", "JASMINE.RICE", "ITALIAN.RICE", "ORG.SIDE.DISHES", "COUSCOUS", "QUINOA", "FLAVOURED.RICE", "INSTANT.RICE", "PARBOILED.RICE", "RTH.SPECIALTY", "RTH.RICE", "OTHER.RICE", "REGULAR.DRY.RICE", 
"READY.TO.EAT"), row.names = c(1000L, 1004L, 1007L, 1008L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: Can you provide the dataset `data_no_demographics`? You can get a copy/paste-able version with `dput(data_no_demographics)`

Comment: The way you posted your data, it would be very tiresome to copy it into my R session. Have you tried the `dput` command?

Comment: I did, and the output is too huge to be posted here

Comment: How about applying `dput` to a subset. For example `dput(data_no_demographics[1:6,])` for the first 6 rows.

Comment: I havent used this function too often, but is the above how the output should be?

Comment: That message doesn't mean R is dead, it means it's busy. Try waiting a bit longer.

Comment: I have tried till about six hours.... It just freezes and continues to do so till I manually shut it down

Comment: I think you forgot a comma. `dput(data_no_demographics[1:6,])`, not `dput(data_no_demographics[1:6])`

Comment: Yes, I did !! My bad, Its fixed now and the output is the edited. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had a test run with the data you provided and found some warnings because of the usage of `silhouette`. Changing `silhouette(km.res$cluster, scale(data_no_demographics))` to `silhouette(km.res$cluster, dist(data_no_demographics))` removed the warnings.

```
data_no_demographics <- data.frame(
  DRY.FOOD.MEAL.PREPARATION = c(0, 0, 0, 0),
  BASMATI.RICE =c(0.106274747, 0.086781763, 0.066892377, 0.039564525), 
  JASMINE.RICE = c(0.037947215, 0.101672855, 0.025094901, 0.026354222), 
  ITALIAN.RICE = c(0, 0.006335413, 0, 0), 
  ORG.SIDE.DISHES = c(0, 0, 0, 0), 
  COUSCOUS = c(0.014091056, 0.013493856, 0.009541397, 0.006704727), 
  QUINOA = c(0.013921964, 0.020977683, 0.011593311, 0.006638343), 
  FLAVOURED.RICE = c(0.322163823, 0.225682349, 0.378639581, 0.340580191),
  INSTANT.RICE = c(0.063184297, 0.044711557, 0.092459218, 0.152615507),
  PARBOILED.RICE = c(0.065396593, 0.089652796, 0.048548271, 0.032295539),
  RTH.SPECIALTY = c(0.010371018, 0.011771236, 0.009418283, 0.007833245), 
  RTH.RICE = c(0.307790945, 0.286375991, 0.29621422, 0.336331652), 
  OTHER.RICE = c(0.013020136, 0.019484745, 0.010382682, 0.006737918), 
  REGULAR.DRY.RICE = c(0.045838206, 0.093059756, 0.051215759, 0.044344132), 
  READY.TO.EAT = c(0, 0, 0, 0), 
  row.names = c(1000L, 1004L, 1007L, 1008L)
)
# omit columns that are just zeros
data_no_demographics <- data_no_demographics[-c(1,5,15)]

library(cluster)
k_max<-3
sil<-rep(0,k_max)
distance_matrix <- dist(data_no_demographics)
for(i in 2:k_max){
  km.res <- kmeans(scale(data_no_demographics), centers = i, nstart = 1)
  ss <- silhouette(km.res$cluster, distance_matrix)
  sil[i] <- mean(ss[, 3])
}
plot(1:k_max, sil, type = "b", pch = 20,col="black",frame = FALSE, 
  xlab ="Number of clusters (k)", 
  ylab="Average silhouette width (fit of data within its cluster)", 
  main="Optimal number of clusters")
abline(v = which.max(sil), lty = 2, col="red")
```

[image]

## EDIT

I just moved the computation of the distance matrix (`dist`) outside of the loop. This should speed up computations if more rows are used.

Comment: Thanks, Because of this I know that the problem occurs when I use the scaled dataset in the loop. However, I am worried because I want to use the scaled data set as that gives a different optimal number as compared to using dist(data), and I have been under the impression that using scaled data may be better for this analysis as there is so much skewness in the data

Comment: Using `silhouette(km.res$cluster, scale(data_no_demographics))` is certainly incorrect. The alternative would be `silhouette(km.res$cluster, dist(scale(data_no_demographics)))` which gives almost the same results

Comment: The documentation of `silhouette` states that if it is used with two arguments, the second needs to be a [distance matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_matrix). `scale(data_no_demographics)` is a rescaled version of your data. It has the same dimenstion as your data and is therefore not square in general. Since distance matrices are always square, this can't be right.

Comment: Thank you so much, Gregor !